# How to array current users count on webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I cant figure out how to array all users on website. Current all users are 5, all I want is just to array number 5 with code. I tried:

```
   <?php
       require 'db.php';
       if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT count(id) FROM users")); {

       $row = $result->num_rows;
       var_dump($row);
       }
  ?>
```

It should show on website Registered users: 5, I tried for hours and cant getting an issue clear... .Somehow i figure out to array int(1) or int(5) on website, have no idea how... All I need to count how many users is in database and array just that number on site.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to Display Current Users Online

Based on your code, I only modified it;

```
<?php
require 'db.php';

if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE status='Online'")); {

$row = $result->num_rows;
$userCount = count( $row );

echo "Total User Online : " . $userCount;

// for debugging 
var_dump($row);
}
```

#### Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. It seems like its working perfect, but I dont know why its showing Total Users: 1 when in database there is 5.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder
You dont need to count(id) on your query, because it will return only one row. Just use (*)  there should be give a correct result

Comment: @Svajukas what's output of `var_dump( $row ) ; `?

Comment: Nice catch @Gagantous

Comment: You are welcome @Svajukas ! Upvote my answer please to help others

Answer (score 1):

Your query already returned the integer with count(*id). No need for num rows. Or no need count(*id) if you use num_rows.

```
<?php
   require 'db.php';
   if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users")){

   $row = $result->num_rows;
   var_dump($row); // this will dump the whole
   echo $row; // this will display the value of 5
   }
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code and then i get result on website "int(5) 5" this int(5) shouldnt be there.

Comment: so, remove var_dump($row). That int(5) came from var_dump($row). var_dump is used to display the whole variable type and the value.

Comment: Thanks! Tick the answer and vote up will be appreciated